# Need to create a type 2 dimension table based on existing table that is recording history?

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I need to create a table recording history of changes like a Type 2 Dimension table based on a Audit table that we already have

Is there any documentation or code that I can build upon. Basically the dates have to line up as shown below in the new table.

[image]

[image]